# Google certificate-transparency build error: `configure: error: cannot find install-sh, install.sh, or shtool`

Tags: build, shtool

I got this error from the `gclient sync --disable-syntax-validation` command while building Google's [certificate-transparency](https://github.com/google/certificate-transparency):

`configure: error: cannot find install-sh, install.sh, or shtool`

in spite of the fact that shtool was in fact installed.

Answer (score 0):

Although I did have shtool installed, I must have installed it after I had run the configuration command (`gclient config --name="certificate-transparency" https://github.com/google/certificate-transparency.git`).

I deleted the `ct` directory (i.e. all the source code downloaded from github), reran the config command and `gclient sync --disable-syntax-validation` and this time did not experience the error.